# Typescript how to make a mapped type extends typeof Class

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

Typescript mapped types syntax is really obscure to me, but I will try to make myself clear.

Basically I want a type filter to return me only the keys of an object that have a type of an Class or an array of classes. After some tries, I ended up with this:

```
type OnlyObjectProperties<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]: T[key] extends object ? key : never;
}[keyof T];

export type ClassRelation<T> = {
  [key in keyof Pick<T, OnlyObjectProperties<T>>]: string;
};
```

But I want the `OnlyObjectProperties<T>` to only return the keys where the type is an class.

For example:

```
class Person{
    name: string;
    task: Task // consider that Task class is defined.
}

const test: ClassRelation<Person> = {tasks: 'tasks'} // only the task key should appear and be allowed on the test variable
```

I already tried something like this:

```
type OnlyObjectProperties<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]: T[key] extends new(...args: any[]) => any? key : never;
}[keyof T];
```

But without success.

To summarize, I want the keys of a given type, that have a type of a Class

This is the stackblitz I've been using to prototype https://stackblitz.com/edit/ts-node-gckhuf?file=index.ts

Comment: There is one problem: declaring a property of type `Task` does not allow to retrieve the "is an instance of the `Task` constructor" info. It could be any value that has at least `Task` properties

Comment: You might be looking for a *construct signature* (when you say “a class” you are presumably talking about a class *constructor*).  It looks like you did try that “without success” but haven’t provided a [mre] of what actually happened. Could you edit your code to something anyone could paste into a standalone IDE and see what you’re seeing?

Comment: I'm Sorry @GuerricP but I didn't understant what you meant. Can you try to explain again?

Comment: @jcalz I tried to provide a little bit of code that can be pasted into the IDE. But there's not much I can provide i'm affraid. I don't know how to "debug" TS behavior except for trying to assign what should be invalid for the type I want

Comment: Oh so you don't want class *constructors*, you want class *instances*.  The TypeScript type system has no way to denote "instance of some class"; that almost makes no sense because every object is an "instance of" its `constructor` property, even ones that weren't declared with `class` syntax.  So `extends object` is what you want, as in your original definition.  [Looks fine to me](https://tsplay.dev/w6Xy0m).  Apparently that doesn't work for you because you are asking the question, so what's the problem?  If you can't convey the issue via [mre] I'm not sure I can do much 

Comment: Hey @jcalz I'm sorry if I didn't make myself clear. What I want exacly, is an object wich have the name of the keys of objects that are of class type. i.e given a class User with a property of type Task (wich is an class), I want my ClassRelation<User> to have a property of name task that gives a string. This is because I'm doing a sort of "mapping" of my Entity Relationships using TypeORM Metadata. TypeORM gives me the info about relationships, but it does  not give info about the types for intelisense. The Object type is not what I want because it Allows Date...

Comment: ...Objects to pass trough ClassRelation<T>, and I expect that only the keys that have a type of a Class (or class constructor as you stated) to be allowed.

Comment: But `Date` is a “class” also, it’s just one that you didn’t write.  So you will need to come up with some principled way to distinguish between what you’re calling a “class” and plain old objects. In any case, what I need to see here is a [mre], code that demonstrates your issue. You could have communicated the issue with `Date` in your code example. Please review the [mre] page.

Comment: You're right, Date is also a Class, I completly forgot that is not a primitive type and also have a constructor. So I guess i'm out of luck, I can distinguish my classes to built-in ones in run time with metadata, but i don't know how to do this with TS types it looks impossible but i would prefer not to believe that. 

This is the stackblitz I'm using to try to figure out how to do this:
there's some extra little stuff that i've been experimenting
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ts-node-gckhuf?file=index.ts

Comment: What kind of metadata?  Maybe all of your "class"es have a numeric `id` property?  Then [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBepdw) should work.  If that is acceptable I will write up an answer. I suggest that you [edit] your question for the benefit of future readers; refactor all the edits into a single question with a single [mre] code with no typos. Additional syntax convention note: the identifier before the `in` in a mapped type is a *type parameter*, not a dummy key name; you should name it the way you'd name other generic type parameters, like `K`, and not like a dummy key name like `key`.

Comment: Thanks @jcalz that actually solves my problem quite well! I believe I can continue myself from now on, thanks for all the tips, you could use this as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really distinguish an instance of a `class` from any other `object` in TypeScript or JavaScript.  All objects have a `constructor` property, even objects provided natively like `Date`.  Instead, you need to find some way to identify the class instances you'd like to preserve, and to distinguish them [structurally](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) from other object types.

The example classes you gave look like this:

```
class User {
  id!: number;
  createdAt!: Date;
  tasks!: Task[];
}
class Task {
  id!: number;
  doneAt!: Date;
  user!: User
}
```

both of which have an `id` property of type `number`.  If that's a good way to tell good class instances apart from bad ones, then you can just change your type function accordingly:

```
export type ClassRelation<T> = {
  [K in keyof Pick<T, OnlyPropertiesWithANumericId<T>>]: string;
};

type OnlyPropertiesWithANumericId<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends { id: number } ? K : never;
}[keyof T];
```

And you can verify that it works as intended:

```
const onlyRelationsFromTask: ClassRelation<Task> = {
  user: "user"
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/MYGwhgzhAECqEFMBO0DeAoa0CWATAhAFzQB2ArgLYBGyA3JtMEgmAC4K4CCrR0AImwT0srSAGsIvACriA2gF16AX3ShIMGRDFoGeXuWp0GuAPYkE3XgPbDoZREl7xk6FegQAPAA4mkraKwAnl4I0ADC4FAASgjgrNhmADxSAHzQALw6WLIA0jgk0GIIgSYAZtAACtjAYskANNAA8iQggRVIJiF+2AgQAOrYrAAWnABylMjVAJK4ySkp8sQQrEjYJADmyvToQSFNLW0dXfG9A8NjE6vAM3MZWdC5+YXFZdBSi2+58tCe7CS4MFQOFwxAMNBQSmgAH5oHlQQgAG5GJSyIolcrvbbAMzLaBmVoxOIJEgQABiHQomjExAi6kJbGJyXEaUyGCw9mQxAARBykFzXOh0EA)